What is the best way to call a Snowflake stored procedure that performs DML and returns multiple values?
Below is a simple example. The final CALL fails with an error

SQL compilation error: Invalid statement type 'INSERT' for child job from stored procedure in FROM clause on TABLE 'EXAMPLE'

The specific purpose is to call a stored-procedure that (a) performs an INSERT and (b) returns multiple values from another stored procedure that then uses the values returned.
Code example 1 - fails:
--NB: This TABLE must exist for all Code Samples. Not repeated. ---
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE EXAMPLE
(
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXAMPLE_WITH_INSERT()
RETURNS TABLE (
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36) ,
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ 
)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36);
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ;
    RESULT RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    ID_STRING:=UUID_STRING();
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
    INSERT INTO EXAMPLE(ID_STRING,INSERT_TIMESTAMP) SELECT :ID_STRING,:INSERT_TIMESTAMP; -- Appears to be causing the error later on...
    RESULT :=(SELECT :ID_STRING ID_STRING,:INSERT_TIMESTAMP INSERT_TIMESTAMP); 
    RETURN TABLE(RESULT); 
END
$$
;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALLER_WITH_INSERT()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36);
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ;
BEGIN
    SELECT ID_STRING,INSERT_TIMESTAMP INTO ID_STRING,INSERT_TIMESTAMP FROM TABLE(EXAMPLE_WITH_INSERT()) ;
    RETURN CONCAT(ID_STRING,'@',INSERT_TIMESTAMP::VARCHAR) ;
END
$$
;

CALL CALLER_WITH_INSERT(); -- Fails "Invalid statement type 'INSERT' for child job from stored procedure in FROM clause on TABLE 

Code example 2 - succeeds (but doesn't perform the INSERT). Unfit.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXAMPLE_NO_INSERT()
RETURNS TABLE (
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36) ,
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ 
)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36);
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ;
    RESULT RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    ID_STRING:=UUID_STRING();
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
    -- INSERT removed.
    RESULT :=(SELECT :ID_STRING ID_STRING,:INSERT_TIMESTAMP INSERT_TIMESTAMP); 
    RETURN TABLE(RESULT); 
END
$$
;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALLER_NO_INSERT()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36);
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ;
BEGIN
    SELECT ID_STRING,INSERT_TIMESTAMP INTO ID_STRING,INSERT_TIMESTAMP FROM TABLE(EXAMPLE_NO_INSERT()) ;
    RETURN CONCAT(ID_STRING,'@',INSERT_TIMESTAMP::VARCHAR) ;
END
$$
;

CALL CALLER_NO_INSERT();

The workaround I have is to return a scalar OBJECT holding the return values.
Code example 3 - works. Is there a better way?
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXAMPLE_WITH_INSERT_WORKAROUND()
RETURNS OBJECT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36);
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ;
BEGIN
    ID_STRING:=UUID_STRING();
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
    INSERT INTO EXAMPLE(ID_STRING,INSERT_TIMESTAMP) SELECT :ID_STRING,:INSERT_TIMESTAMP; 
    RETURN OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('ID_STRING',:ID_STRING,'INSERT_TIMESTAMP',:INSERT_TIMESTAMP); 
END
$$
;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALLER_WITH_INSERT_WORKAROUND()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    RESULT OBJECT;
BEGIN
    CALL EXAMPLE_WITH_INSERT_WORKAROUND() INTO RESULT ;
    RETURN CONCAT(RESULT:ID_STRING,'@',RESULT:INSERT_TIMESTAMP::VARCHAR) ;
END
$$
;

CALL CALLER_WITH_INSERT_WORKAROUND();

The following examples show that the stored procedure EXAMPLE_WITH_INSERT() can be called but its RETURN value not (as far as I can tell) 'treated' as TABLE despite (well) being declared as a TABLE. However, the stored procedure EXAMPLE_NO_INSERT() doesn't have the same problem.
CALL EXAMPLE_NO_INSERT();
SELECT CONCAT(ID_STRING,'@',INSERT_TIMESTAMP) FORMTTED FROM TABLE(EXAMPLE_NO_INSERT());

CALL EXAMPLE_WITH_INSERT();
SELECT CONCAT(ID_STRING,'@',INSERT_TIMESTAMP) FORMTTED FROM TABLE(EXAMPLE_WITH_INSERT()) -- FAILS
;

NB: all constructive executable answers will be welcomed and most likely upvoted even if I don't find them better than my workaround. There are lots of ways to skin this cat!

Hi - can you explain why you need to have two SPs? If this is not a strict requirement the there are probably a number of solutions - as you’ve found, the issue is that you can’t embed a SP in a SQL statement and use it like a UDF

The aim is structured programming. The real case is INSERTs Rows in a TABLE. It performs some validation and then populates some standard fields (such as actioning User ID) and so on. It's called from multiple locations. You can call embed an SP in a SQL statement and use it like a UDF and Snowflake SQL specifically permits RETURNing a TABLE-like object as in RETURNS TABLE (/*...*/ above. It also allows DML such as INSERT in stored-procedures. It just has limitations about doing both in the same stored-procedure (apparently!).

@marc_s Many thanks for the copy editing.

This may not be totally relevant to your use case but I code all my core processes in (often jinja-templated) SQL files held in a Snowflake stage. I then use SPs to validate input parameters and manage the flow-of-control before calling the relevant SQL file(s) using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FROM... statements

It is possible to intercept and process resultset from inner stored procedure in outer stored procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALLER_INSERT()
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36);
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ;
    RES RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    res := (CALL EXAMPLE_INSERT());

    LET cur1 CURSOR FOR res;

    -- assumption that single row is returned
    FOR rw IN cur1 DO
        ID_STRING := rw.ID_STRING;
        INSERT_TIMESTAMP := rw.INSERT_TIMESTAMP;
    END FOR;

    RETURN CONCAT(ID_STRING,'@',INSERT_TIMESTAMP::TEXT);
    
END ;

Key points:

Inner stored procedure returns resulset (multiple columns)
Outer stored procedure intercepts results  res := (CALL EXAMPLE_NO_INSERT());
Opening cursor for resultset LET cur1 CURSOR FOR res;
Cursor FOR loop for handling returned values  FOR rw IN cur1 DO ... END FOR


Inner stored procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXAMPLE_INSERT()
RETURNS TABLE (
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36) ,
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ 
)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
    ID_STRING VARCHAR(36);
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ;
    RESULT RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    ID_STRING:=UUID_STRING();
    INSERT_TIMESTAMP:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

    INSERT INTO EXAMPLE(ID_STRING,INSERT_TIMESTAMP) 
    SELECT :ID_STRING,:INSERT_TIMESTAMP; 
    
    RESULT :=(SELECT :ID_STRING ID_STRING,:INSERT_TIMESTAMP INSERT_TIMESTAMP); 
    RETURN TABLE(RESULT); 
END;

Output:

